# img-fluid not correctly resizing image height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, fluid-layout

I am working with Bootstrap 4 and am trying to have a grid of 4 images, 2 on top and 2 on bottom. I am using the `img-fluid` class but the image resizes based on the width only making the image height too large and it is getting cut off. I tried setting `max-height: 100%` but that didn't work.

What's going wrong?

```css
.images-container {
  height: 95vh;
}

.nav-button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: black;
}

.footer-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.bottom-nav-box {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
}

.sim-image {
  max-height: 100%;
}

i {
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

footer {
  height: 5vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-sm-10 h-100 center-container">
  <div class="row  images-container">
    <div class="row top-images-row h-50">
      <div class="w-50 d-inline-block image-div">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/875/656/" class="sim-image" id="simulatorImageTopLeft">
      </div>
      <div class="w-50 d-inline-block image-div" id="simulatorImageTopRight">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/875/656/" class="img-fluid sim-image" id="simulatorImageTopRight">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row bottom-images-row h-50">
      <div class="col image-div center-block text-center">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/875/656/" class="img-fluid sim-image" id="simulatorImageBottomLeft">
      </div>
      <div class="col image-div center-block text-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col center-block text-center">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/875/656/" class="img-fluid sim-image" id="simulatorImageBottomRight">
          </div>
          <div class="col center-block text-center">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/875/656/" class="img-fluid sim-image" id="simulatorImageBottomRight">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What size are the images? Do you expect the images to maintain the same aspect ratio?

Comment: The image is 875x656. I would like them to maintain the same aspect ratio

Comment: I don't see the images being cut off. Can you include a screen-shot of what you see? Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure I'm interpreting the question correctly, but if you want a 2×2 grid of images then you should just be able to do it relatively quick like this;

**html:**

```
<div class="panel">
     <img src="blah" />
     <img src="blah" />
     <img src="blah" />
     <img src="blah" />
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.panel {
     width = whateversizeyouwant;
     height = whateversizeyouwant;
     display: flex; 
     flex-wrap: wrap;    //the flex stuff should make it display 2×2
}

.panel > img {
     width: 50%;
     height: 50%;
}
```

That should work for any set of 4 images.

If you want them to stay the same aspect ratios then under `.panel > img` set `height: auto`. Keep in mind this won't give you a perfect square, and the size of the `panel` div will impact how the images can be sized.

Comment: That solved the problem for me. Looks like I was overthinking the problem too much. Simple divs with images worked perfectly. No bootstrap needed.